# PHP script working with sql query but error message not showing just blank

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a PHP script that works as in I get the desired results but can not work out why when I put in a blank query my error message does not show instead I get all results. Can anyone shed some light on this. When an input value is entered that does not match the database the error message works it is just blank queries. I can control with javascript (validation) but would prefer if I understood whats wrong with my script.

I have looked at over questions that suggest the use of isset( which I tried to apply but obviously not correctly.

I was thinking of

```
if( isset...){

post [query];

}
else{

do not post ;
```

but am not applying correctly (this above is from another question) but not sure if correct. Below is my script giving the undesired behavior:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$userinputone = isset($_POST['abc'])? $_POST['abc'] : false;

$userinputone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$userinputone);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM handover WHERE batch1number  = '".$userinputone."' OR        

batch2number = '".$userinputone."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0 ){
echo "</br></br></br></br></br></br></br><p> No Matching results found</p>";
}

else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "</br></br></br><select>";
echo "<option>" . $row['batch1number'] . $row['batch2number'] . "</option>";
echo "</select>";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: thankyou. I looked at the link: ("SELECT * FROM handover WHERE batch1number = '".$userinputone."' OR        

batch2number = '".$userinputone."' ";) I take its not as simple as putting the query in brackets.

Comment: Brackets have nothing to do with it. You should be using `?` instead of `$userinputone`, then making a call to bind that value to the placeholder before executing it. Any time you mix in arbitrary strings you put yourself at severe risk of introducing a SQL injection bug, so avoid doing it unless you have no other option, and even then be extremely careful to escape things properly. The way you've done it here with manual escaping and string concatenation leads to mistakes.

Comment: Thanyou Tadman. I will look at your link more closely and try and adapt my script. This is going to be used locally at the charity I work for on an intranet so hopefully SQL injection will not be so much of an issue. I will also add some javascript to help with sanitizing user input. If I can adapt I will as this is also a learning opportunity for myself.

Comment: SQL injection is *always* an issue, don't be like that. Do it right and there won't be problems, and the right way is actually less complicated and easier to read than the hard way where you're escaping manually. Do it wrong and you're creating a ticking time-bomb. You have zero control over how this code is used in the future. What's private today might be public tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I guess isset will be equal to true if the parameter is empty, try other functions like is_empty, is_null, intval(), floatval() etc... and always dump your params to check what they contain, so it's not as accurate as you may think, and also pay attention to SQL Injection.

Comment: Where would i apply the empty(). i put it in place of the isset and got the same behavior also tried the other suggested options.